# Como puedo abrir adobe acrobat para android

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo un problema haber si podéis ayudarme,genero un fichero pdf en la memoria interno,miro en el device file explorer y encuentro dicho fichero pero luego si voy a mi movil y lo busco con un explorador o el adobe ese fichero no existe,no lo encuentro por ninguna parte y lo que intento es que llamo a la aplicacion de adobe para poder leer dicho pdf pero me da error.

Codigo que genera pdf:

```
private void generarInforme() {
        try {
            File carpeta = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "PDF_MANU");
            if (!carpeta.exists()) {
                carpeta.mkdir();
                Toast.makeText(informes.this, "Creando carpeta en:" + carpeta.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            ficheroPDF = new File(carpeta, "prueba_PDF.pdf");
            documento = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(ficheroPDF));
            documento.open();

            //crear parrafo
            documento.add(new Paragraph("Informe generado para el usuario: " + usuarios.getNombre() + " " + usuarios.getApellidos()));

            //meter linea espacio en blanco
            documento.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            //Crear tabla
            PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(3);
            for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {
                tabla.addCell(datos.get(i).getConcepto());
                tabla.addCell(String.valueOf(datos.get(i).getCantidad()));
                String fecha = convertidorFecha(datos.get(i).getFecha());
                tabla.addCell(fecha);
            }
            documento.add(tabla);
            documento.close();
            Toast.makeText(informes.this, "Fichero pdf generado en" + ficheroPDF.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("generarInforme", "" + ficheroPDF.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Lugar donde se encuentra el fichero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ruta donde supuestamente me dice que esta el fichero:

```
/data/user/0/com.example.cuentas/files/PDF_MANU/prueba_PDF.pdf
```

Y el error que me da al intentar usar el metodo de visualizar pdf:

```
private void visualizarInforme() {
        Toast.makeText(informes.this, ficheroPDF.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(ficheroPDF), "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Y el error que me da:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cuentas/com.example.cuentas.informes}: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/PDF/Prueba_PDF exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/PDF/Prueba_PDF exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1960)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2356)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9881)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9835)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1610)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
        at com.example.cuentas.informes.visualizarInforme(informes.java:77)
        at com.example.cuentas.informes.almacenamientoExterno(informes.java:49)
        at com.example.cuentas.informes.onCreate(informes.java:42)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Gracias.

Comment: Te indica que debes de usar FileProvider para poder abrir archivos en otras apps -> [Documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider), al igual que ya debes tener los permisos de `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` y `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` en el archivo `Manifest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Palacio y tras buscar información con fileProvider ya he conseguido que muestre el adobe cuando intento visualizar un pdf que haya generado mi aplicación.

```
private void visualizarInforme() {
        if (ficheroPDF.exists()) {
            Uri ficheroCompartido = getUriForFile(control.this, "com.example.cuentas", ficheroPDF);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setDataAndType(ficheroCompartido, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "No Application Available to View PDF",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(control.this, "No se encontró el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Gracias por la ayuda @A.Palacios